# How to get the newest (last modified) directory [C#]

Tags: c#, directory

Currently my application uses string[] subdirs = Directory.GetDirectories(path) to get the list of subdirectories, and now I want to extract the path to the latest (last modified) subdirectory in the list.

What is the easiest way to accomplish this?
(efficiency is not a major concern - but robustness is)

Comment: Should it be recursive (all descendants)?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

without using LINQ

```
DateTime lastHigh = new DateTime(1900,1,1);
string highDir;
foreach (string subdir in Directory.GetDirectories(path)){
    DirectoryInfo fi1 = new DirectoryInfo(subdir);
    DateTime created = fi1.LastWriteTime;

    if (created > lastHigh){
        highDir = subdir;
        lastHigh = created;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use of `DateTime lastHigh = DateTime.MinValue` would be safer than an explicit point in time.

Answer (score 60):

Non-recursive:

```
new DirectoryInfo(path).GetDirectories()
                       .OrderByDescending(d=>d.LastWriteTimeUtc).First();
```

Recursive:

```
new DirectoryInfo(path).GetDirectories("*", 
    SearchOption.AllDirectories).OrderByDescending(d=>d.LastWriteTimeUtc).First();
```

Answer (score 3):

Be warned: You might need to call `Refresh()` on your Directory Info object to get the correct information:

e.g. in Laramie's answer you'd edit to:

```
DirectoryInfo fi1 = new DirectoryInfo(subdir);
fi1.Refresh();
DateTime created = fi1.LastWriteTime;
```

Otherwise you might get outdated info like I did:

> "Calls must be made to Refresh before attempting to get the attribute
>   information, or the information will be outdated."

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.refresh(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
string pattern = "*.txt"

var dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(directory);

var file = (from f in dirInfo.GetFiles(pattern) 
            orderby f.LastWriteTime descending 
            select f).First();
```

http://zamirsblog.blogspot.com/2012/07/c-find-most-recent-file-in-directory.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Directory.GetLastWriteTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getlastwritetime%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) (or `Directory.GetLastWriteTimeUtc`, it doesn't really matter in this case when you're just doing relative comparisons).

Although do you just want to look at the "modified" time as reported by the OS, or do you want to find the directory with the most recently-modified file *inside* it? They don't always match up (that is, the OS doesn't always update the containing directory "last modified" time when it modifies a file).

Comment: Most recent FOLDER (files insider are irrelevant)

Comment: In that case, `Directory.GetLastWriteTime` is what you're after. Laramie's solution also works, which is pretty much as I was saying (he was just kind enough to write the code for you ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you are building a windows service and you want to be notified when a new file or directory is created you could also use a [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(VS.71).aspx). Admittedly not as easy, but interesting to play with. :)

Comment: -1 This only works if the directory is created while the application is running, which isn't necessarily true based on the information provided in the question.

Comment: That is exactly why I specified a windows service, implying it's going to be running all the time.

Comment: That's not necessarily true. Services can be started and stopped, or run intermittently (I would argue that's a poor design, but that's a separate issue). This method would not notify the application if a folder was created before the application was *installed*, for example.